# Load value of register in 2 by 2 bytes to another register

Tags: assembly, memory-management, cpu-registers, z80

I am learning Z80 assembly programming for the Amstrad CPC, and then I need to get the address from
a list of two byte hex values, but for the moment I know how to get 1 by 1 byte (using 'A' register).

I have a "table" of addresses named 'map' that stores random video memory addresses.

for example:

```
map:
dw #C630, #C6E8, #C73D, #C78F

;;for C630 address is 4007
;;for C6e8 address is 4009
;;for C73D address is 400B
;;for C78F address is 400D
```

I could access It with index register instructions (ix or iy) but while I'm learning more, I undestand that index registers can pushed and popped or load 'A' register whith only 1 byte, not 2 bytes as I need.

My question is:  there is some method to get the 2 bytes address (4007) and load the COMPLETE ADDRESS (4007) in a register and then load the COMPLETE VALUE (C630) of this address and not only 1 by 1 byte using 'A' register?

Something like if this Z80 instruction exists:

```
ld hl,(ix)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You urgently need to obtain a programmer's manual for the Z80 that includes a detailed chapter on its instructions. Use your web search skills to find one.

There are instructions do implement this.

For example you can read a 16 bit value from an absolute address:

```
    ld  hl,($4007)
```

If you have the address in a register pair, unfortunately there is not single instruction to read a 16 bit value via this "pointer". But you can do it in a few instructions:

```
    ld  hl,$4007
    ; hl now has $4007

    ld  e,(hl)
    inc hl
    ld  d,(hl)

    ; optionally, if needed to restore the original address:
    dec hl

    ; alternatively, if needed to advance to the next address:
    inc hl
```

BTW, experienced Z80 programmer try to avoid using IX and IY because of the worse performance compared to HL (1 more M1 cycle, 1 more M2 cycle, and some clocks for addition per load operation, as well as 2 more bytes per instruction). For example, you could write:

```
    ld  l,(ix)   ; actually "ld  l,(ix+0)" that is sometimes clearer
    ld  h,(ix+1)
```

But this will "cost" 38 clocks and 6 bytes, while the former example needs 26 clocks and 4 bytes.

If you need *a real lot* of loading and do not need the stack for processing, you can abuse the stack pointer. I found this trick in a Gameboy game. Its processor is quite similar to the Z80 but lacks the repeated load instructions like `ldir`.

```
    ; don't forget to save the SP somewhere else, if necessary...
    ld  sp,$4007
    pop hl
    ;...
    ; restore the SP
```

Comment: Just to add, if you want HL to point to the next 2-byte value, you can change that `dec hl` to `inc hl`. (That's usually the behavior that I need.)

Comment: Why not answer using the registers he asked for in the question: `ld l, (ix); ld h, (ix+1)`.

Comment: @prl OP is asking of "_some method_" so any register is fine.

Comment: Indeed, for big chunks of data, the stack trick is usually the fastest, but it requires you to temporarily disable interrupts (`DI` ... `EI`), otherwise interrupts generated by Amstrad CPC hardware (300 times per second) will clobber memory near `SP`.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and It works for me:

```
ld hl,map
ld e,(hl)
inc hl
ld d,(hl)
inc hl
push hl      ;then popped in a loop
ex de,hl
ld (hl),#ff
map:
dw #C630, #C6E8, #C73D, #C78F
```